# jQuery: Prevent changing of disabled state on element where possible

Tags: jquery

I have the code below. It first gets all buttons with a class of edit to not be disabled.

It then issues a get request to see which files are locked and disabled the buttons accordingly.

This works fine. However as people can be editing all the time, it's run on an interval of X seconds so refreshes for the user as they view the page.

If I set it to something like a second, any button that needs to be disabled will first be active and then be disabled - the problem is the shade of green changes so it looks like it pulses.

Hopefully this makes sense. What's the best way around it.

There are about 500 buttons in total representing 500 different records so what I didn't want to do is loop through each button and check if that exists in the array I get back as thought that could be inefficient especially if the majority of the rows are locked.

The JSON I get back is in the form:

```
[ { "id": "4", "name": [ "Jo Bloggs" ] } ]
```

**Function**

```
function checkLock() {
    $("button.edit").prop('disabled', false);
    $.get('/listLockedFiles/json', function(data) {
        var id;
        var name;
        var currentUser;
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $.get('/currentUser', function(cu) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                id = data[i]["id"];
                name = data[i]["name"];

                if (name !== cu) {
                    $("button.edit[data-id=\""+id+"\"]").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```